# How can I define an object as one type, then later declare it as a sub-type?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code that needs to read in data, either from an istringstream or an ifstream. I don't know much about C++, but my experience in other languages tells me I should just have a variable that's an istream (the parent type of ifstream and istringstream), and then later set it to either an istringstream or an ifstream. Here's what this might look like in, say, Java:

```
String word;
IStream stream;

if (someCondition) {
    stream = new IStringStream("banana");
} else {
    stream = new IFStream("apple.txt");
}

while (word = is.read()) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

This type of syntax would work no problem in Java and other similar languages, but I can't get it to work in C++. Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
string word;
istream stream;

if (someCondition) {
    string mystr = "banana";
    istringstream stream(mystr);
} else {
    string myfile = "apple.txt";
    ifstream stream(myfile);
}

while(stream >> word) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

This doesn't compile, with the error on the 2nd line: "no matching constructor for initialization of 'istream' (aka 'basic_istream')". What can I change to make the C++ code work like the Java pseudocode example I wrote above does?

Comment: Remember, everything is java is a pointer, they just hide that from you.  If you want to do the same thing in C++ you actually have to use a pointer, to um well... make a point.

Comment: _but I just know nothing about C++_  No way, you need to learn the language if you want to work on it

Comment: @HaydenSchiff *Here's what this might look like in, say, Java:* -- Don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  All you will wind up doing is having code that is buggy, inefficient, and just plain-old weird looking when a C++ programmer looks at the code.  Learn C++ as if Java doesn't exist.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, thank you for that advice. I just arbitrarily used Java as an example because I needed some way to convey what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are coming from Java, a quick rule of thumb is that for polymorphic objects you need a pointer (asterisk `*`), a reference (ampersand `&`), a smart pointer, or some other way of setting up indirection.

Here is an example of the syntax that would fix the problem:

```
string word;
istream *stream;

if (someCondition) {
    string mystr = "banana";
    stream = new istringstream(mystr);
} else {
    string myfile = "apple.txt";
    stream = new ifstream(myfile);
}

while((*stream) >> word) {
    // do some stuff
}

delete stream;
```

**Note:** This solution is not ideal, because you end up deleting the stream manually. A better approach would rely on a smart pointer, which deletes your object automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the part that uses the stream in a function that takes a `std::istream&` and then just pass in whatever you want to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

void useStream(std::istream& stream) {
    std::string word;
    while (stream >> word)
        std::cout << word << ' ';
}

int main() {
    if (someCondition) {
        std::string str = "The best program in the world";
        std::stringstream foo(str);
        useStream(foo);
    }
    else {
        std::ifstream file("text.txt");
        useStream(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: For general code organization (making the streaming code a function), this is ok.  The issue is that in the `main`, how do you write the code to choose either `stringstream` or `ifstream`?  That's what the answer @dasblinkenlight suggests.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You just add `if/else`... ? I doesn't seem to me like that is what the question is asking. It's asking about a how to deal with a generic `std::istream`.

Comment: Think of the code duplication if you had 4 different stream types in `main` instead of 2.  That same call to `useStream` would be written 4 times.  Choosing the type dynamically, and then making one call to `useStream` with that dynamically chosen type would be preferable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't really understand what you're getting at. Are you saying this approach would create more code duplication? How?

Comment: Yes, your approach would create duplication.  Thought I explained it quite well how it does it.  Why not try it?  Attempt to write code that picks the stream type and then calls `useStream` once.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If that is a concern, nothing is stopping you from choosing the type dynamically and passing that in. It seems strange to pick on details that are more your assumptions then anything clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Comments are for comments, so I commented.  Your answer misses what the OP was doing in main, and that was choosing the stream dynamically.

Comment: I like this solution very much as it avoids dynamic allocation. However it would be better if you put the `if` statement in explicitly mirroring what the OP is doing.